# Can I setup IVR on my Android phone?

Tags: android, ivr, dtmf

I think to make it possible I need to make the app automatically respond to the incoming calls. Is that possible at all?

I want to build an android application for small business. Using this application a business owner can:

- setup a custom IVR menu
- Auto forward calls to another number depending upon at what time the call has been made and what option has the user chosen in the IVR menu
- Automatically dial-in (merge call) another number in the call

Is it possible to do all this?